# Does Google Sheets have a function to insert X number of Y characters within a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

I currently have a spreadsheet which requires a variable number of line breaks within a cell based on input data from another cell.

Long story short, I currently am using a brute force method to accomplish this, via a lengthy IFS() statement where each condition has one more instance of "CHAR(10)" than the previous.

[image: My function as is, which is an IFS() function]

It gets the job done, but it's very bloated.  **I might be taking a wild shot in the dark here, but is there *any* function (or series of functions) that adds x number of y character to a cell?**  Or would I have to create something myself via custom function or apps script?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [rept()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134):

### *Syntax*

***`REPT(text_to_repeat, number_of_repetitions)`***

***`text_to_repeat`** - The character or string to repeat.*

***`number_of_repetitions`** - The number of times `text_to_repeat` should appear in the value returned.*

*The `number_of_repetitions` can’t exceed the character limit of a cell, 32,000 characters. If `number_of_repetitions` is greater than 32,000 characters, `REPT` will return a `#VALUE!` error.*